# Area between two graphs

Tags: calculus

I want help with following questions:

An area A is enclosed by $f(x) = x+1 $ and $g(x) =7$ and the y-axis.

1) Calculate the value of this area A

2) Calculate the volume $V_x$ when the area $A$ is rotated $360$ degrees about the $x$-axis.

My solution:

1) I draw the two graphs and found the two boundaries to be $y_1 = 1$ and $y_2 = 7$, so:
$A = \int_{1}^{7} g(x) - f(x) dx = \int_{1}^{7} 7 - (x+1) dx  = 12$

Is my answer to question 1 correct? How do I make question 2?

Comment: You have the bounds for y, but you are integrating with respect to x.  And draw a picture, this problem is easy to solve with jr high-school goemetry.  Your calculus should give you the same results.

Answer (score 1):

For the first answer see the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ioykycwcg2)

$$x+1=7$$
$$x=0,6$$ are the bounds
$$\int_{0}^{6}7-x-1dx=18$$
**Hint:**

For the second part use Disc-Method

$$\pi\int_{a}^{b}\left(R^2-r^2\right)dx$$

where $R=$outer radius, $r=$ inner radius

In your problem $a=0, b=6, R=g(x)=7,r=f(x)=x+1$

Comment: OP's first answer is wrong. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ydp5yanacb)

Comment: I just realized it

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you seek the area between the intersections of $x+1$ with the y axis and the line $y=7$. These happen at $x=0$ and $x=6$, and due to the perpendicularity of the two axes, they form a right angled triangle with a height of $6$ and a base of $6$ too. So the area is $$\frac 12 * 6 *6 =18$$This can also be found by $$\int_{0}^{6}{7-(x+1)dx}=\bigg[6x-\frac12x^2\bigg]^6_0=18-0=18$$

With the second integral, use the formula for volume of revolution:
$$V=\pi\int{y^2dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

For part $1) $ change your limits to $$ A = \int_{0}^{6} g(x) - f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{6} 7 - (x+1) dx  = 18$$

For part 2)  use the integral $$ V = \int_{0}^{6} g^2(x) - f^2(x) dx $$